# PicklingError: Can't pickle suds.sudsobject.User: attribute lookup suds.sudsobject.User failed

Tags: django, suds

I have a django application... I am accessing the web service using the SOAP suds client... I need to create a user object from the entries entered in the GUI... This user object is to be passed to a method... But i get the following error:

PicklingError: Can't pickle suds.sudsobject.User: attribute lookup suds.sudsobject.User failed

What is the cause for this error to occur???

Answer (score 2):

As of now I don't know of a way to pickle a Suds client object - as an intermediate step suds has implemented a caching mechanism that will help load times. Obviously, it would be a very handy option. See this ticket for some information on the issue and some specific challenges for Suds and pickling: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/154

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps trying to pickle an object that cannot be pickled. See here: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled